# Where to download Chrome version 17?

Tags: google-chrome, download, version

I'm trying to find a download link for Chrome 17 for Linux x64. The reason I want this, for the curious, is that it's for a security course - we're implementing the CRIME TLS compression attack, and we need an old browser that still supports TLS compression. I've found a few links on sketchy-looking websites that I'd rather not trust, but nothing official-looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion in the one of the google groups might help https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/Z-UroWhOhX0

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Hi, Glad that helped. If you think this ultimately helped you then please mark this as the accepted answer.